# How can I make query simpler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails 5 app.
In this app I got a method that gets values from child objects and adds them to an hash. The below method/code works perfectly fine but I how can I make it better in terms of speed and structure?

```
def generated_values(period, year, month, quarter)
        count = 0
        score = 0
        actual = 0
        goal = 0
        red = 0
        if stype == "measure"
            measures.period(period, year, month, quarter).each do |measure|
                count += 1
                score += measure.score
                actual += measure.value_actual
                goal += measure.value_goal
                red += measure.value_redflag
            end
        elsif stype == "objective"
            children.each do |child|
                child.measures.period(period, year, month, quarter).each do |measure|
                    count += 1
                    score += measure.score
                    actual += measure.value_actual
                    goal += measure.value_goal
                    red += measure.value_redflag
                end
            end
        elsif stype == "scorecard"
            children.each do |child|
                child.children.each do |child2|
                    child2.measures.period(period, year, month, quarter).each do |measure|
                        count += 1
                        score += measure.score
                        actual += measure.value_actual
                        goal += measure.value_goal
                        red += measure.value_redflag
                    end
                end
            end 
        end
        values = { :score => score == 0 ? 0 : (score / count).round, :actual => actual, :goal => goal, :red => red }
    end
```

Comment: You'll want to post this in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), not stack. :)

Comment: Can you do it in sql? What are the model relationships? Are `score`, `value_actual`, `value_goal` and `value_redflag` columns in the database? Side note, `score == 0 ? 0 : (score / count).round` can be simplified to `(score / count).round` (It would be better to check if `count == 0`)

Comment: you could probably use `case.. when` instead of `if..else if` .. but that'll give you structure .. at the cost of speed .. little Heisenberg situation there

Answer (score 0):

I think I would be tempted to do something like:

```
def generated_values(period, year, month, quarter)

  case stype
  when "measure"
    selected_measures = measures
  when "objective"
    selected_measures = child_measures
  when "scorecard"
    selected_measures = grandchild_measures
  end

  count = selected_measures.count

  {
    score:  count > 0 ? (selected_measures.sum(:score)/count).round : 0,
    actual: selected_measures.sum(:value_actual)
    goal:   selected_measures.sum(:value_goal) 
    red:    selected_measures.sum(:value_redflag)
  }

end
```

Untested and off-the-cuff.

Naturally, the most interesting part is the `selected_measures =` bits. But, you haven't provided enough information to help with the proper formulation of those queries.